# ActionScript 3: Jump to a specific frame and target a MovieClip in that frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs5

I'm trying to do some stuff in Flash. Let's say I have a MovieClip called **mcShape** with three frames. In each frame there is a different shape that masks another movie clip, in another layer, that spans for the said three frames. That movie clip is called **mcColor** and defines the color seen through the shape, thus rendering the desired shape in the desired color:

[image]

From the main timeline, on the frame where I have **mcShape**, I've written the following code:

```
mcShape.gotoAndStop(some frame);
mcShape.mcColor.gotoAndStop(some other frame);
```

The thing is this doesn't work. When I don't change mcShape frame, everything works fine, but when I gotoAndStop some other mcShape frame, mcColor is not detected anymore and I get *Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference*. Even if I put three different frames with a different instance of mcColor on that frame, it doens't work.

Are there any workarounds to this? What am I doing wrong? Thank you very much!

Comment: are you sure that in each keyframe there is an instance name of `mcColor` attached to the movie clip?

Comment: It is one long frame, yes, but even if I put three keyframes with an instance of mcColor attached to each it doesn't work :c

Comment: are you able to share your .fla?  That would be easiest to understand what's going on.

Comment: Yes, here it is https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1O4spaz01QMVUJBT3NLay1SMUE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Works fine for me, no modifications. What version of FlashPro are you using? CS5 (that's what you tagged)?

Comment: Works fine for you? No errors? No 1009? When you run it the shape stays with only one colour? That's so weird! I'm using CS3 - I tagged CS5 because it had more exposure.

Comment: That's right. Works as you'd expect without issue.  I'm using the latest AdobeAnimate though,  CS3 is pretty old.  Though there shouldn't be anything difference in what you're doing.

Comment: Well, I haven't tried it on Animate. I'll try it there and tell you if it works for me - or my computer is jinxed or something, ahaha. Thank you very much!

Comment: Works as a charm! Post your answer so I can choose you as the best answer :D Thank you very much!

Comment: Except it's not really an answer.  I can't tell you why it doesn't work.  You can answer your question yourself if you'd like.

Comment: Well, it worked for me, but you are right. Thank you very very very much for your help! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to Adobe Animate seems to have solved the problem.